# $PATH being ignored in python virtualenv for bin

Tags: python, virtualenv, fabric

I have a virtualenv, and in that virtualenv I'm attempting to run a fabfile.

The fabfile starts like this:

```
import httlib2
```

when I try to execute

```
fab --list
```

to get a list of available tasks, I instead get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 658, in main
docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 165, in load_fabfile
imported = importer(os.path.splitext(fabfile)[0])
File "/Users/user/Documents/code/fabfile.py", line 5, in <module>
import httplib2
ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

yet when I do:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2013, 10:53:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
>>>
```

it imports just fine!

I checked which fab is being executed:

```
$ which -a fab
/Users/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/fab
/usr/local/bin/fab
/usr/local/bin/fab
```

and my $PATH starts with:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin:
```

There is something I'm missing here, but for some reason it doesn't see httplib2 when I execute fab. It appears that the wrong fab is being executed (i.e. not the first one found in my $PATH), but I can't explain how or why.

If I do a pip freeze, I get:

```
$ pip freeze
Fabric==1.8.3
ecdsa==0.11
httplib2==0.9
paramiko==1.12.4
pycrypto==2.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Long shot, but you didn't expressly say it so did you do `source /Users/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate` ?

Comment: @Victory yes, the virtualenv was sourced

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why, but after deactivating the virtualenv and reactivating it, everything works fine now...

Answer (score -1):

$PATH is used by your terminal. You want $PYTHONPATH, or, in python:
import sys; sys.path.append("somedir")

See https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables for more about environment variables in python.

It looks like your "fab" command is using a different interpreter than where your pip and other terminal session are coming from. You can either change the path with one of the above, install httplib2 in the python env fab will run from, or enforce that fab uses your other python.

Comment: That doesn't really help. The shell should be executing the first hit in the $PATH that resolves, which is to:

    /Users/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/fab

If I explicitly execute it, fab works fine!

    $ /Users/user/.virtualenvs/deployinator/bin/fab --list

    Available commands:
    ...